# Capybara: Finding li element

Tags: capybara

Using Capybara, I'm trying to test that the first  contains "Shop".

The code looks like this:

```
<h1 aria-haspopup='true' class='dropdown-toggle title' data-toggle='dropdown' tabIndex='0'>
Dashboard
<span class='caret'></span>
</h1>
<ul aria-label='Dashboard Menu' class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
<li class='dropdown-header' role='presentation'>Recent Projects</li>
<li role='menuitem'>
<a href="/tkim/shop"><span class='recent-project-access-icon'>
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
</span>
<span class='str-truncated'>
<span class='namespace-name'>
tkim33
/
</span>
<span class='project-name filter-title'>
Shop
</span>
</span>
</a></li>
<li role='menuitem'>
<a href="/tkim/asdfadfsdsafdasf"><span class='recent-project-access-icon'>
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
</span>
<span class='str-truncated'>
<span class='namespace-name'>
tkim33
/
</span>
<span class='project-name filter-title'>
asdfadfsdsafdasf
</span>
</span>
</a></li>
<li role='menuitem'>
```

But I don't know how to assert whether the first  contains "Shop".

I started out with:

find(:css, '.navbar-gitlab .dashboard-menu .dropdown-menu'), but I don't know how to traverse to make sure that the first li element contains my expected result.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
page.all('li')[0].text.should == 'Shop'
```